# Find the last number in a text string

Tags: excel

I want to find the position of the last numeric character in a text string. I'm using this formula to do so:

> MAX(IF(ISERROR(FIND({1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0},A1)),"",FIND({1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0},A1))

However, this doesn't work if the string contains repeating numbers.

For instance, when the string is "10ABC2010ABC" it will return 6 instead of 9. 
When the string is "10ABC2131ABN" it does return 8 instead of 9.

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: `I want to find the last numeric character` - or position of last numeric character?

Comment: Yes the position, basically what I'm doing is stripping the letters that appear after the last numeric characters. Using the LEFT function to do so and the position that is returned by the function presented here.

Comment: I assume the real data is more varied than your examples, presumably the last digit could be at a position other than 9.....or there will be more or fewer letters at the end?

Comment: Yes the real data is more varied and can be any combination of letters and numeric characters

Comment: Don't know about sweeter......but I was looking at some other options using MATCH as per CRondao and this one works for me and is shorter still - `=MATCH(2,1/MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))`

Comment: @barryhoudini, unfortunatelly formula `=MATCH(2,1/MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))` doesn't work if last number in string is zero `0`, say `123aa0bb` returns 3 while should return `6`

Comment: it should be something like this `=MATCH(2,1/(1+MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1)))` (not tested)

Comment: Yes, forgot about zero - your one works...or perhaps just convert to a number and use 10 as lookup value, i.e. `=MATCH(10,MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1)+0)`

Comment: @barryhoudini You can handle 0 and remove the array entry like this also `=MATCH(0,INDEX(-MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1),0))` AS index will create the array and by negating the value in A1, it will error all alphas, and negate all numeric and return the last position of any number. Adding the `-` to the beginning is basically like adding the `+0` to the end. I just through it into an Index so it won't have to be array entered. any number in the first part of the match should work also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is working formula:

```
=MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))),1))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1)))))
```

press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it.

**Explanation:**

- `ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1)))` returns you array `{1,2,3,...,Len(A1)}`
- using this array we can take each character in `A1` cell: `MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))),1)`
- using `VALUE(...)` we tries to convert each character to number. It returns `#VALUE!` error for all characters exept 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0
- using `ISNUMBER(...)` we check whether `VALUE(..)` returns number or error, and if it returns number, we remember it's position.
- final step - using `Max(..)` we find last position of numeric character

Comment: Will not work all the time, returns the wrong value with string like this:  "A.L.A. 669.711n j"

Comment: it returns 14 for me. And `=Left(A1,MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))),1))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))))))` returns `A.L.A. 669.711` as expected

Comment: Sorry @simoco you're right it returns 14, it is the formula from Barry that is returning 13 :)

Comment: @CRondao, I get 14 for `A.L.A. 669.711n j`using my MAX formula - did you array enter?

Comment: I think I know what is the problem, it is the maximum of a matrix so one of the arrays should be transposed. with this it works TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))))

Answer (score 3):

`FIND` only finds the position of the **first instance** of each number so it won't work for your requirements. Try using this formula

`=MAX(IFERROR(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))),0))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

That also uses `FIND` but the `ROW(INDIRECT` part starts the search further along the string on each occasion. If there are no digits in A1 you get zero as the result (you could make that an error if you want)

Another possibility if you are using Excel 2010 or later is to use AGGREGATE function like this: [untested]

`=AGGREGATE(14,6,FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))),1)`

That doesn't require "array entry"

See [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dr76loqfl0xv9ab/last%20number.xls) for sample workbook with suggested formulas

Comment: I went with more complex way, but the idea is the same:)

Comment: I can't test the AGGREGATE function right now but I get 9 for 123aaa123, as expected

Comment: I suspect that's a regional settings issue - are you changing my formula, replacing commas with semi-colons? If so then that isn't the correct "translation", commas used as separators in the formula can be replaced with semi-colons, commas in the "array constant" should be replaced with \ so for Germany\France\other European countries use `=MAX(IFERROR(FIND({1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9\0};A1;ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))));0))`

Comment: Oh!! yes! this one returns correct result: `=MAX(IFERROR(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};A1;ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))));0))`

Comment: @simoco - which regional settings are you using?

Comment: Yeah, know it works, and it is the transpose thing. In my regional settings {1;2;3} returns a vertical array but {1,2,3} returns a horizontal array (the same as transposing {1;2;3} :)

Comment: Yes, it needs to be a horizontal array because the ROW(INDIRECT is returning a vertical array.....I added a workbook to my answer with simoco/barry/CRondao formulas

Answer (score 2):

And this array formula will also work... ok, ok... I know it uses offset :)

```
=1+LEN(A1)-MATCH(1;ISNUMBER(LEFT(RIGHT(A1;ROW(OFFSET(A1;0;0;LEN(A1);1))))*1)*1;0)
```

Comment: Along similar lines......`=MATCH(2;1/ISNUMBER(MID(A1;ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)));1)*1))`

Comment: @barryhoudini fantastic, great improvement :)

Comment: thanks - even better, you don't need ISNUMBER....`=MATCH(2;1/MID(A1;ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)));1))`